# Are there any out of the box alternative to Spring's Async annotation?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, guice, aspectj

I am using Guice as DI (not using Spring anywhere now) and have the requirement of executing some task asynchronously. When I used Spring earlier I just annotated the method with @Async and everything used to work as expected i.e. method getting executed asynchronously. But without Spring I don't have that feature hence I want to know if there is any out of the box equivalent of Spring's Async which I can use without writing the code for creating/configuring executor and using it.